# When you are going to know indirectly / politely the name of the person you're meeting or talking to

Tags: idiomatic-language

Please imagine you're going to know the name of someone very politely at first meeting. E.g. in a party or similar occasions.

In my mother language, there is a specific way of saying the same thing. This is a translation. Please let me know if it word in English? If yes, does it sound natural or it is considered to be too formal?

> - And to whom do I have the pleasure of meeting with?

If it is not natural, then please let me know what shall I say instead?

The same goes with the first phone conversation.

> - And to whom do I have the pleasure of speaking with?

Please let me know if it requires some clarifications.

Comment: Just a note: it would be "to whom **do** I have..."

Comment: also **To whom do I have the pleasure of speaking?** is enough. So, **with** is technically incorrect.  However, I would only see or hear this in a TV drama like *Downton Abbey*, most of us don't speak like this everyday.

Comment: @JamesP the point is taken. I edited the thread. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: @WillowRex it seems old-fashioned to me too. Did I follow you? Is it a little odd to you too to be heard in daily conversations? If so, how would you ask it indirectly?

Comment: Very formal and so yes, old-fashioned. I suppose if I were to meet a dignitary, I might possibly speak like that. I don't know how or why to ask indirectly. I'd ask directly. " I'm sorry, I don't know your name." Or, "My name is Willa, what is yours?" "I may have forgotten your name, have we met before? My name is Willa."

Comment: But where I live in luxurious parties and ceremonies, some stuff shirt people have such a tongue trick to get familiar with girls @WillowRex.

Comment: If you want to talk about pick-up lines, we should take this conversation to a chat room. :wink:

Comment: **to whom do I have the pleasure of meeting with?** is not correct because you're using two prepositions - you meet *with* someone, not *to* someone, and you certainly don't meet *with to* someone, and in this case you don't need any preposition.  Think about how you would phrase it as a statement: "I have the pleasure of meeting..."?  You would normally say "I have the pleasure of **meeting you**", not "meeting *with you*" or "meeting *to* you" or "meeting *with to* you".

Comment: @stangdon, so my comment was still incorrect? It should be ,**"Whom do I have the pleasure of speaking?"** That still sounds so awkward.

Comment: @WillowRex - No, because you do *speak to* or *speak with* someone...so *To whom* or *With whom* is correct.  But "meet" isn't like that, so the question would be "Whom do I have the pleasure of meeting?"

Answer (score 3):

This is considered quite a formal way of addressing someone.

I would probably say something like:

"Sorry, I don't think I know your name."

and then wait for them to tell me.

Alternatively, reaching out for a hand shake and saying your own name "Hi, I'm ..." will work just as well, as the other person will more than likely reciprocate.

This would keep your question slightly more casual and will generally work in most scenarios. I generally use the hand shake approach at job interviews.

On the phone: I will generally say, "Hello, this is ..., I would like to speak to someone about..." and hopefully the person on the other end will direct you to the right place or be able to help you out themselves.

Comment: My father who is in his nineties, cannot remember names. So he says, "Hello, I remember my name, it's William. Do you remember yours?"  I'd always ask this way, "Hello, I am (or my name is) Willa R. This is my husband, Jack. May I know your name? (Or, less formally,) What's your name?"

Comment: @WillowRex good job. :)) I'm having a laugh attack because of the way you explained your intent here and can't stop my laughter. Anyway; does your offer: **"May I know your name?"** work both in phone and face to face conversation? (laughing again.) :)

Comment: @A-friend Yes it works on the phone, too. Though I tend to ask, "May I know/ask who is calling? Or, "I'm Willa, what's your name?" I find by offering my own name, people are more inclined to simply say their own name. I also call it fishing for information. "Hi, I'm Willa." This usually suggests that the other person should offer their name.

Comment: "May I know your name" seems rather uncomfortable for me to say as a native English speaker.

I would probably say, formally, "Can I have your name please?" for example to a customer or enquirer at a place of work if I was required to take their name.

"What's your name?" works great informally.

Comment: @MichaelCurry I am in my sixties, and can and may do not mean the same to me as they do to you. Yours is more modern and might be more AmE. *May* is politely asking permission. *Can* is saying, "Am I able to get your name?" The answer to *can* is if you are capable, then yes. The answer to *may* is, ** if you have permission**.

Comment: @WillowRex this is a well spotted distinction, however, I wouldn't say that it's an important distinction in this day and age. The vast majority of people now use 'may' and 'can' interchangeably in every day language (which would include in the workplace.) The only time I would be very particular about this is in a piece of academic writing. In speech, whether it is face to face or over the phone, I think 'can' is widely accepted by a large majority of English speakers. It has been about 15 years since someone has pointed this distinction out to me.

Comment: @MichaelCurry I am an old retired teacher. :wink: And I am Canadian. I think it makes a difference where you are, too. I know my Texan husband (he was educated in Connecticut), when hiring college grads for his IT Department notices this sort of thing in an interview. It doesn't mean that person would not get hired, but it is noted.

Comment: @WillowRex For the record, I lived in Zimbabwe whilst I was quite young, and then in the UK since. I think the biggest difference between people noticing it is very age based, rather than due to a place.

Edit: I keep pressing enter without finishing my comment

Although, like I said, I think it's a very well spotted distinction, but I don't think it's a very important one. It may make someone who is very picky about grammar and language perk their ears up in discomfort, however I don't think it would particularly affect a day to day conversation any further than that.

Comment: *whilst* ? Oh there's a word I have not seen in years... It is fun to figure all this out and discuss it though. I said I thought it was age based and I actually agree with you, but I still say, *"May I"* and not *"Can I"* unless I mean can. **Can I still touch my toes?** (For the record, I can!) :wink:

Comment: @WillowRex As someone in their early twenties who can't touch their toes (due to being unfit, not due to having no toes), I can say that I'm quite impressed that you are able to touch your toes. It seems as though I missed that you were saying that you thought it was a combination of both rather than just being location based. I guess we were in agreement all along. :)